# Docker - Access mapr UI from host

Tags: docker, mapr

I have installed docker on a CentOS machine. Now I am trying to run a MapR sandbox on it. After starting I get this:

```
Starting MapR Services.................
To manage this node go to: https://172.17.0.13:8443
```

But I am not able to access this URL from the windows machine in the same network as the CentOS machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an internal docker network inaccessible outside of the box. In order to access this container you need:

- [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose) command in container (most likely it is already there)
- run container with [-p option](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports)

If you just specify -p port will be random - you could find it with inspect command, or you could use permanent port -p hostIp:externalPort:8443 where hostIp is address of your docker host.

After that you could access container from network as https://hostIp:externalPort

Comment: Hey @ISanych, Thanks for the reply. But when I am trying the command with -p option, I get this error `Starting MapR Services.....Failed to start CLDB...`. On the contrary I see the **CLDB** process running for the other nodes which are not started with the -p command.

Comment: I don't see how -p could affect container. It maps container ports to host ports, but inside of container everything should be the same.